# Raspberry PI and TV output

Tags: hdmi, output

Today I bought my Raspberry Pi and want to build an ambilight for my TV. I know how to do this and will get it to work.. however, what I would like to know is if I can somehow get the output from my TV to the PI as well? 
My TV uses an DVB-T reciever which is built-in into the TV... so there are no HDMI cables in between.

I have an LG 55LM620T-ZE, and I am not able to find anything in the documentation on how to get the video out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video source needs to be 'tapped'. e.g. a satellite box or RF aerial as the source and then a USB dongle plugged into the Pi.
alternatively for project you could wire up colour detecting diodes, say, one per corner of the TV.

Comment: Ok... so no. =P I'll have to either use an external DVBT reciever or use only the XBMC variant. thanks